# Excess of Redis connections created and idle connections not used

Tags: redis, connection, pool

Following is my jedis pool configuration:

```
Excess of connections are created as the existing ones are not used. What is the     purpose of pool if every function creates new connection.

Please let me know if anybody can provide solution to this.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  `<bean id="jedisConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
<property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
<property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
<property name="whenExhaustedAction" value="2" />
<property name="maxIdle" value="40" />
<property name="minIdle" value="30" />
<property name="softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="60000" />
<property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="600000" />
</bean>

<bean id="jedisFactoryPrimary"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="poolConfig"><ref bean="jedisConfig"/></property>
    <property name="hostName" value="${redis-db.hostname}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${redis-db.password}"></property>
    <property name="port" value="${redis-db.port}"></property>
</bean>`
```